# Eclipse Nsight: Insisting synchronization error

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nvidia, remote-debugging, nsight

I'm getting really often the following message from Eclipse Nsight when I try to compile my code on a **remote target system** (in particular, a Jetson TK1):

[image]

[image]

I guess it happened because the remote system crashed in the middle of synchronization and I had to restart it. Is there a way to synchronize the two projects? So far I've been resolving the issue by creating a new project and copying the source files...

Answer (score 1):

Nsight uses Git to synchronize changes between systems (this way it avoids overwriting the changes by mistake).

What most likely happened is that you now have inconsistent Git repositories. Do you need your remote copy? The easiest way would be to simply delete remote copy and then do a sync to create a complete copy. Note that Nsight keeps some synchronization state in-memory so you may need to restart the IDE before this "first sync"

If you need your remote copy because you've made any changes to it, then setup a new synchronization location, force Nsight to create a new copy, copy the changed files from an old copy into the new copy.